# how to access the inventory details of an item master record using suitescript 1.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I need to just get the Qty on hand, qty on order, qty backordered, under which bin number the item is, value and avg. cost of an item. Just need to show this to my manager in a normal text field.
I tried to do it from search, but the values were not according to the inventory details.

My manager is saying me not to use search and use loading the subrecords but i couldn't find any idea for loading subrecords.

My Current code on client script:

```
function pageInit() {

   var itemSearch = nlapiSearchRecord("item", null,
    [
      ["name", "haskeywords", "ZE001156"],
    ],
    [
      new nlobjSearchColumn("itemid").setSort(false),
      new nlobjSearchColumn("displayname"),
      new nlobjSearchColumn("location"),
      new nlobjSearchColumn("quantityonhand"),
      new nlobjSearchColumn("quantityonorder"),
      new nlobjSearchColumn("quantitybackordered"),
      new nlobjSearchColumn("averagecost"),
      new nlobjSearchColumn("binnumber")
    ]
  );
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'itemSearch', JSON.stringify(itemSearch));
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'itemSearch.length', itemSearch.length);
  if (itemSearch.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < itemSearch.length; i++) {
      var srchLine = itemSearch[i];
      var onHand = srchLine.getValue('quantityonhand');
      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'on hand:' + i, onHand);
      var onOrder = srchLine.getValue('quantityonorder');
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to view this articles
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27978/kw/Suitescript%20sublist%20subrecord/related/1
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27977/kw/Suitescript%20sublist%20subrecord/related/1

I highly discouraged using 1.0 version of Netsuite. It will be unsupported soon and obsolete.

Comment: Thanks james, You are absolutely right but because i m working under someone's supervision therefore i need to follow his order...

Comment: No worries, but you can advised him regarding the version that you should use. I am working directly with NS so kindly save yourself for later trouble